# How do I use Image Capture to wirelessly scan to my Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, image-capture

How do I use Image Capture to wirelessly scan from Brother MFC-490cw flatbed to my Mac OS X?  I go to Image Capture and get an Overview scan, but then cannot actually scan the image next.  Wher

Answer (score 1):

To the right of the scan overview, there should be a pop-up list named *Auto Selection*. If it's set to *off*, then you should either select an option from there or select which part of the overview image to be scanned yourself by clicking and selecting the image.